# for statement > tokens issue

Tags: batch-file

I want to create a command in my own command prompt that runs a command.

So I set a sample variable. Here it is:

```
set m=sample -gtc new -args sample
```

So I tried using `for` in order to get the command after `-gtc` and after `-args`.

So this is my `for` command:

```
for /f "tokens=3,5" %%e in ("%m%") do echo %%e
```

The command responded. But it only responded like `tokens=3` meaning the command only echo-ed the one after `-gtc` not including the `-args`.

I followed the way https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html said.

> *tokens=2,4,6 will cause the second, fourth and sixth items on each line to be processed*

So the same way what will happen in my command right? It's just like this.

> *tokens=3,5 will cause the third and fifth items on each line to be processed*

Comment: It works, but you don't output the 5th element. It is in %%f. Try echo %%e %%f

Comment: Thanks, jeb! Thank you!

Comment: Should you create a comment so I can mark it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use `FOR /F` with multiple tokens, the fetched tokens are stores in  subsequently FOR /F variables.

In your case `for /f "tokens=3,5" %%e in ("%m%") do echo %%e` 
The first token at position 3 is stored in `%%e` and the second token at position 5 is stored in `%%f`