# batch - Make if statement ignore unwanted inputs

Tags: windows, batch-file

I can't figure out how to detect additional inputs in set /p

for example:

`set /p glass=` for example they typed `user {random letters}` there

The original input I wanted is only `user`

How can I make batch ignore the additional random letters the user input?

Comment: How are we supposed to know where the random characters start?

Comment: Are you looking to only grab things before the first space?

Comment: And you already know how to break up a string based on a space as the delimiter from your last [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47863327/for-statement-tokens-issue)

Comment: I'm looking for what SomethingDark said.

Comment: @scriptmastere02, what didn't you understand about the answer in your last question on how the the `FOR /F` command breaks up a string.  You literally had the answer to your question already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set /P "uName=Please enter your name here: "
Echo Hello %uName: =&:%
Timeout 3 /NoBreak>Nul
```

Comment: It works. But how can I apply this to an *if* statement?

Comment: `If /I Not "%uName: =&:%"=="%uName%" Echo Why so formal? I thought we were on first name terms!` If you need to know how a command works, the simplest way is to enter the name of the command at the prompt, followed by the question mark option, `If /?`.